# JSON get a value if another value

Tags: javascript, json

Okay so my JSON is something along the lines of:

```
{
    "wares":[
      {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"apples",
        "stock":"40",
      },
      {
        "id":"2",
        "name":"pears",
        "stock":"40",
      },
      {
        "id":"3",
        "name":"bananas",
        "stock":"30",
      }
   ]
}
```

So I would like to get the name if the stock is 40, I've used this code as an example, which I found here: http://techslides.com/how-to-parse-and-search-json-in-javascript/

```
function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));    
        } else 
        //if key matches and value matches or if key matches and value is not passed (eliminating the case where key matches but passed value does not)
        if (i == key && obj[i] == val || i == key && val == '') { //
            objects.push(obj);
        } else if (obj[i] == val && key == ''){
            //only add if the object is not already in the array
            if (objects.lastIndexOf(obj) == -1){
                objects.push(obj);
            }
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

which works, but I haven't quite found a way to return the name if the stock is 40.

I was thinking you put an extra value in the function called ret (return) as in what it should return. Something along the lines of

```
alert(JSON.stringify(getObjects(JSON, 'stock', '40', 'name')));
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate solution using the native `filter()` and `map()` methods:

```
function getObjects(_object, _key, _value, _return) {
  return _object.filter(function(_item) {
    return _item[_key] == _value;
  }).map(function(_item) {
    return _item[_return];
  });
}
```

Note that in the above call, we need to pass the array containing the items, not the root object. *Or you can modify the above to accept the root object*

And you call it like:

```
getObjects(obj.wares, 'stock', 40, 'name');
```

to get back `["apples", "pears"]`

Comment: This is a really useful method as well, and doesn't use jquery. This also returns all wares in one beautiful line rather than several, both methods really good and it all comes down to preference. I thank you too techfoobar!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out!

```
$.each(getObjects(JSON, "stock", "40"), function() {
    alert(this.name);
})
```

EDIT: Just in order to explain what I wrote, the getObjects function returns all the objects that matches the search criteria, so then what I did was to get each name of all the JSONS that are returned

Comment: That's much more simple than I expected it would be! Amazingly simple, quick and worked beautifully. Thanks!